# Committee Selection Feud

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From a group of 4 men and 5 women, how many committees of size 3 are possible with 2 men and 1 woman if 2 of the men are feuding and refuse to serve on the committee together?

The indirect method of solving this problem is to do the following :
Total number of possible cases = 5C1 * 4C2 = 30
No of ways feuding men serve together = 2C2 * 5C1 = 5
Answer = 30 - 5 = 25

However, i wanted to solve this problem using the direct method. I tried to split the 4 men into 2 groups, one group was the feuding group of 2 men, and the other 2 were the passive ones. Then i chose 1 man from the feuding group and 1 man from the passive group. May i know what is wrong with this logic?
5C1 * 2C1 * 2C1 = 20

Comment: please use `$n \choose r $` to use $n \choose r$

Comment: You can also use `$\binom{n}{k}$` to produce $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the case where you may choose both men from the non-feuding group.  This adds $5$ more possibilities.  Your expression counts only those cases where one man is selected from each of the feuding and non-feuding groups.